# Explaining DrawArc method?

Tags: c#, winforms, draw

I have a task in which I have to draw a **Figure of Eight**, so I thought of it as drawing four arcs. I tried using the `DrawArc` method but I really don't understand how does it work at all.

The `DrawArc` method takes 4 parameters:
1-The pen.
2-Rectangle to draw in.
3-Start angle.
4-Sweep angle.

What I don't get is the start and sweep angle, could anybody with knowledge tell me what are these 2 parameters and how do they effect the drawing ?

Also does giving the rectangle parameter takes the (0,0) as starting point.

Edit:

I have tried the following code:

```
        e.Graphics.DrawArc(drawPen, 0, 0, 600, 400, 45, 90);
        e.Graphics.DrawArc(drawPen, 0, 345, 600, 400, -45, -90);
```

which resulted in the following:

[image]

I would like to make it larger, I have played with the code but not success, I didn't understand what I am doing, I was just changing numbers, that is why I asked for an explanation.

Comment: Did you go crazy and [read the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142028.aspx)? It seems like it explains what those parameters mean fairly well. What part didn't you understand? Have you written some code to play with it and try out various values to see what happens? That's usually how I figure out how things work when I don't understand them.

Comment: Do you honestly think that i have not read the documentation before i came asking here. Let me assume that you really understand everything from the documentation could you please explain to me what is the Start and Sweep angles ?

Comment: @user, the start and sweep angles are pretty well-defined in the docs (respectively *Angle in degrees measured clockwise from the x-axis to the starting point of the arc* and *Angle in degrees measured clockwise from the startAngle parameter to ending point of the arc*). This is further explained in *The arc is the portion of the perimeter of the ellipse between the startAngle parameter and the `startAngle` + `sweepAngle` parameters*. As Cody said, can you clarify what you don't understand there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you imagine 2-D Coordinate axes  and clockwise rotation ,
Start angle : shows the point where you want to start drawing from X axes
Sweep angle : measure of clockwise rotation ,

also MSDN Said:
startAngle: Angle in degrees measured clockwise from the x-axis to the starting point of the arc.

sweepAngle: Angle in degrees measured clockwise from the startAngle parameter to ending
    point of the arc.

for example : Horizantal Arc and Vertical Arc :

```
  switch (ArcType)
        {
            case ArcType.Horizantal :
                g.DrawArc(Pens.Black, 0, 15, 15, 15, 0, -180); 
                break; 
            case ArcType.Vertical:
                g.DrawArc(Pens.Black, 0, 15, 15,15, -90,180);                    
                break;
        }
```

Comment: You wrote: "sweepAngle: Angle in degrees measured clockwise from the startAngle parameter to ending point of the arc". So, it means that sweepAngle = desiredAbsolueEndAngle - startAngle. I think

Answer (score 3):

The coordinates are for drawing a **complete ellipse** from the top and left by width and height. Which part of the ellipse is actually drawn is determined by start and end angles. If the circle is a clock, then 3:00 is 0, 6:00 is 90, 9:00 is 180 and 12:00 is 270.

Comment: I was confused by this as well - then I realized that the start position (x,y) is the top _left-hand corner_ of the bounding box of the complete ellipse. It's not the centre of the ellipse, as you would draw it on paper in Maths.